# Problema ao imprimir array de string de um ponteiro e repetição do método main C++

Tags: c++

Possuo uma classe "Elemento" que possui um ponteiro "itens", do tipo string (da biblioteca string.h), responsável por guardar uma referência a um array de itens do Elemento. Tudo funciona bem, caso eu não execute o app dentro de um while. No entanto, ao usar o while, o programa para de funcionar caso eu tente imprimir os itens do elemento que eu criei anteriormente. Para ficar mais claro, o que eu fiz foi exatamente:

1 - Modificar o elemento

2 - Mostrar os itens do elemento

Ao mostrar os itens do elemento, vários caracteres estranhos aparecem na tela do console e o programa para de funcionar, sem que os itens sejam sequer impressos na tela.

Seguem os códigos da classe e da aplicação:

Classe Elemento:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

class Elemento{

private:

    string *itens;
    int size;

public:

    Elemento(string itens[], int size){
        this->itens = itens;
        this->size = size;
    }

    void showItens(){
        for(int i = 0; i < this->size; i++){
            cout<<endl<<itens[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Código da aplicação:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Elemento.cpp"
#include<string.h>

Elemento *el;

bool loop = true;

int main(){
    while(loop){

        int num;

        cout<<endl<<"1 - Modificar o elemento"<<endl;
        cout<<"2 - Mostrar os itens do elemento"<<endl<<endl;
        cin>>num;

        cin.sync();

        switch(num){
            case 1:{
                int num;

                cout<<"Digite o numero de itens: "<<endl;
                cin>>num;

                string itens[num];

                for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
                    cout<<"Digite o item: "<<i+1<<": "<<endl;
                    cin>>itens[i];
                    cin.sync();
                }

                el = new Elemento(itens,num);

                el->showItens();
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                if(el != NULL){
                    el->showItens();
                }
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                loop = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alguém saberia me dizer a causa desse problema?

// Update

Refiz os código utilizando malloc. Ficaram assim:

Classe Elemento:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Elemento{
    private:

        string *itens;
        int size;

    public:

        Elemento(string itens[], int size){
            this->itens = (string*)malloc(size * sizeof(string));
            this->itens = itens;
            this->size = size;
        }

        void showItens(){
            for(int i = 0; i < this->size; i++){
                cout<<endl<<itens[i]<<endl;
            }
        }
};
```

Classe App:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Elemento.cpp"
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

Elemento *el;

bool loop = true;

int main(){
    while(loop){

        int num;

        cout<<endl<<"1 - Modificar o elemento"<<endl;
        cout<<"2 - Mostrar os itens do elemento"<<endl<<endl;
        cin>>num;

        cin.sync();

        switch(num){
            case 1:{
                int num;

                cout<<"Digite o numero de itens: "<<endl;
                cin>>num;

                string *itens;
                itens  = (string *)malloc(num * sizeof(string));

                for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
                    cout<<"Digite o item: "<<i+1<<": "<<endl;
                    cin>>itens[i];
                    cin.sync();
                }

                el = (Elemento*)malloc(sizeof(Elemento)) ;
                el = new Elemento(itens,num);

                el->showItens();
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                if(el != NULL){
                    el->showItens();
                }
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                loop = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Não sei se é necessário utilizar malloc dentro do construtor da classe Elemento. Creio que o problema no meu código seja iterar sobre o ponteiro 'itens'. Ví em algumas fontes que era possível iterar sobre ele do mesmo jeito que um array, na forma 'itens[indice]'. No entanto, meu programa ainda para de funcionar nessa parte do programa.

Comment: Você está guardando em `el`, um objeto criado na heap, ponteiros para objetos criados na pilha (`items`). Você teria que fazer a cópia de forma manual ou, de preferência, utilizar um contêiner que cuide disso, como por exemplo o `std::vector`.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser, Teria como você indicar algum texto que explique a diferença entre heap e pilha, e como isso se aplica a POO em C++? Estou pesquisando aqui sobre isso pra ver se encontro algo que possa resolver esse problema.

Comment: Tem uma resposta muito boa aqui no SOpt mesmo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-onde-est%C3%A3o-o-stack-e-heap

Answer (score 1):

Existem vários problemas no seu código, vou me concentrar apenas em um deles.

Aqui

```
el = new Elemento(itens,num);
```

Você está criando um objeto anônimo do tipo Elemento, e no construtor do objeto Elemento você inicializa o ponteiro "itens" para referenciar o array de strings "itens" que foi criado no "case" 1 do comando "switch".

Problema: assim que a execução sai do case 1, o array de strings é desalocado, morre, portanto o objeto criado acima agora tem um ponteiro "itens" inválido, apontando para um objeto que não existe mais. Além disso, muito provavelmente a memória do array de strings que foi destruído na saída do case 1 vai ser reaproveitada e sobrescrita, ficando corrompida (no sentido de que não vai mais ser um array de strings, outras coisas vão ser escritas em cima). Por causa disso, se logo em seguida você escolhe a opção 2 para imprimir o conteúdo do objeto Elemento muito provavelmente o programa vai se comportar anormalmente, provavelmente vai ser cancelado por erro.

Comment: eu modifiquei o programa de acordo com o que eu achei na internet sobre alocação dinâmica de memória. Eu usei malloc pra reservar espaço para modificação. No entanto, creio que o meio problema agora seja iterar sobre o ponteiro 'itens'.